# Using recursive DFS to find node in binary tree

Tags: c, recursion, binary-tree, nodes, depth-first-search

I have to use DFS to search a binary tree to find a node. (tok is the string I'm searching for). If it finds it, it has to return the number of nodes it traversed to find it. If it doesn't then it has to return -1.

I have tried many recursive solutions but honestly, I'm stumped. I may not be returning values correctly.

Test case:
Lets say i have a tree with the root called "John"."John" as a left child "Shayne" and a right child "Eric". Additionally, "Shayne" has a left child "Max". The output would be correct for John,Shayne and Max. But the output of Eric should be 4, since i traverse john and then shayne and then max and then Eric (considering im going left first and then right), but for Eric, im getting the output of 3

Edited with exact test case.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node {
    char* name;
    char* tea;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
};

typedef struct node Node;

int depth(struct node* root);
int dfs(struct node* root, char* tok);

int main() {

    Node* John = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    John->left = NULL;
    John->right = NULL;
    John->name = "John";
    Node* Shayne = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    Shayne->left = NULL;
    Shayne->right = NULL;
    Shayne->name = "Shayne";
    Node* Eric = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    Eric->left = NULL;
    Eric->right = NULL;
    Eric->name = "Eric";
    Node* Max = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    Max->left = NULL;
    Max->right = NULL;
    Max->name = "Max";

    John->left = Shayne;
    Shayne->left = Max;
    John->right = Eric;

    printf("%d",dfs(John,"Eric"));
}

int depth(struct node* root) {


    if (root == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    int l = depth(root->left);
    int r = depth(root->right);
    int d = max(l, r) + 1;
    return d;



}


int dfs(struct node* root, char* tok) {


    if (root == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (strcmp(root->name, tok) == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        int l = dfs(root->left, tok);
        if (l != -1) {
            return 1 + l;
        }
        int r = dfs(root->right, tok);
        if (r != -1) {
            return 1+l+ r;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (strcmp(root->name, tok) != 0) { return 1; }` abandons the search at the first mismatch, with apparent success. But `strcmp()` returns `0` when the strings are the same.

Comment: My mistake, i changed it to ==0 but it still didn't work

Comment: `if (l == 1)` and `if(r == 1)` did you mean `if(l >= 0)` etc?

Comment: I compared them both to 1 because i wanna know if the value was found. The base case returns 1 when the value is found

Comment: But as the answer, says, you increment it on the return journey through the recursion.

Comment: So i should increment regardless of finding it or not?

Comment: No, because you haven't found it. Also, I think you need `if (root == NULL) { return -1; }` instead of `return 0;`

Comment: but i still have to increment since i traversed the node anyways, and the question says to tell the number of nodes you traversed to find it. No?

Comment: But if you didn't find it, so how can you know the depth of recursion. What you could do, is *decrement* the negative value, then you'll know how deep the search was.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand sorry

Comment: Look, if you find a key at depth 5 it returns 5 because the original 1 is incremented by every previous call instance. If you search to the last node at say depth 9 without finding the key you can decrement the negative value on the way back and end with -9.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is an inadequate description of the problem. Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest *complete* code that shows what you have tried. The problem might not lie in the function, and nobody can try it without having to write the missing code.

Comment: I edited my question to include the full code, and the test case im testing too

Answer (score 1):

You correctly add 1 to the return value when the value has been found in an immediate child to produce the number of nodes. But it also means that you will return **2** to your parent.

You have to change your test to

```
if (l != -1) { //found on left child
        return 1 + l;
    }
```

Comment: Still not the correct output. I changed the condiiton to this and di the same for the check of r

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with your function is that when you are returning from the child node you are always checking the value of l with 1 for instance:

```
int l = dfs(root->left, tok);
    if (l == 1) { //found on left child
        return 1 + l;
    }
```

which will work fine for the first 2 nodes but then the value of the return becomes 2,3,4,.... in that case it will skip the if and return -1 again, so to solving this problem a good approach will be to check if the return value is not -1, for example:

```
int l = dfs(root->left, string);
    if (l != -1) { 
        return 1 + l;
    }
    int r = dfs(root->right, string);
    if (r != -1) { 
        return 1 + r;
    }
```

Hope this gives you the answer.

Comment: Didn't work. So this works as long as the tree is all left. But lets say i have a tree with the root called "John"."John" as a left child "Shayne" and a right child "Eric". Additionally, "Shayne" has a left child "Max". The output would be correct for John,Shayne and Max. But the output of Eric should be 4, since i traverse john and then shayne and then max and then Eric (considering im going left first and then right), but for Eric, im getting the output of 3